# Compute Engine System service account service permissions issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup an instance schedular for my VM instance to start and end at particular time.
I am getting an error permission related to my google service account when trying to add the vm instance to the scheduler. I have added this roles (Compute Instance Administrator (Version 1),Compute administrator) to my service account via IAM but still getting the same error.
the error message is
"Compute Engine System service account service-xxx needs to have [compute.instances.start, compute.instances.stop] permissions applied in order to perform this operation"

Anyone who has faced similar issue please suggest on how to fix it?

Br,
Ramkrishna

Comment: Which role did you add? Edit your question and list the roles that the service account has. You can find this information in the Google Cloud Console -> IAM.

Comment: included the roles added for the default service account

Answer (score 28):

There are two types of service accounts for Compute Engine.

1. The **default service account** is assigned to the instance.
2. The **Compute Engine Service Agent** is used by Google services to manage your resources.

You assigned the role to the wrong service account. The **Agent** needs the role added.

The Compute Engine Service Agent has the following format:

```
service-PROJECT_NUMBER@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

**Solution:**

- Login to the Google Cloud Console
- To to **IAM & Admin**
- Select **IAM** in the left panel
- Click the box **Include Google-provided role grants** on the right side of the window. This enables showing Google-managed service accounts.
- Locate the service account. Press **CTRL-F5** to open a search box. Enter the text **compute-system**.
- Click the **pencil** icon to edit the service account.
- Click **ADD ANOTHER ROLE**
- In the role filter enter **Compute**. Select **Compute Instance Admin (v1)**.
- Click **SAVE**

Wait a few minutes before trying to use the new permissions.

[Compute Engine Service Agent](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_service_account)

[Scheduling a VM instance to start and stop](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop#before-you-begin)

Comment: Thanks manage to resolve it with the steps mentioned below

Comment: Thanks! saved my day! that checkbox is really tricky one to notice!!

Comment: For once simple guide for google cloud. I don't understand how they've managed to mess up their guides so badly.

Comment: Not sure why GCP docs are always confusing..Thank you lot 